# Update ulimit parameters on ubuntu with out restarting

Tags: ulimit

I am trying to update ulimit open files limit from 1024 to 30000.
but i need this change with out restarting the server?

Even on restarting the server this changes are not reflected 
followed this blog
http://posidev.com/blog/2009/06/04/set-ulimit-parameters-on-ubuntu/

Comment: You're looking for global ulimit or per user ulimit modification?

Comment: and you are using ubuntu right?  it can differ from distro to distro